# boost urdl error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, boost

i'm trying to solve this for couple hours but have to give up:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <urdl/istream.hpp>
using namespace boost;
int main()
{
  urdl::istream is("http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt");
  if (!is)
  {
    std::cerr << "Unable to open URL" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(is, line))
  {
std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I updated the libraries and everything but get this error:

[image]

Comment: Please never post pictures of text. Instead copy-paste the text into the question.

Comment: As for your problem, the very first error says that `boost::array` is undefined. Have you simply tried including the `<boost/array.hpp>` header file before `<urdl/istream.hpp>`?

Comment: I tried but now i get this error: 
Warning 1 warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'std::streamsize' to 'size_t', possible loss of data c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\urdl\detail\file_read_stream.hpp 98

Warning 2 warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'std::streamsize' to 'size_t', possible loss of data c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\urdl\detail\http_read_stream.hpp 443

Error 3 error C2666: 'urdl::detail::asio_handler_invoke' : 3 overloads have similar conversions

Comment: I would say the problem is with URDL (whatever that is), and not with the compiler, Boost or your code.

Comment: It looks like you are using a version of boost that your compiler doesn't support

Comment: Thank you very much for help, you were right about  urdl, i used the version downloaded from original web site. the correct urdl is https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/urdl which fixed compile error when using Boost 1.55